# Rails: Get error on RSpec testing View edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have some errors while testing with RSpec. This is my code:

**\spec\views\post_categories\edit.html.haml_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "post_categories/edit", type: :view do
  before do
    login_user
    @post_category = FactoryBot.create(:post_category)
  end

  it "renders the edit post_category form" do
    render
    assert_select "form[method=?]", "post" do
      assert_select "input[name=?]", "post_category[title]"
      assert_select "textarea[name=?]", "post_category[description]"
    end
  end
end
```

After it I get such an error:

> 1. post_categories/edit renders the edit post_category form
>
>    Failure/Error: = simple_form_for(@post_category) do |f|
>
>    ActionView::Template::Error:
>    No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"post_categories", :locale=>#<PostCategory id: 1, title:
>    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", description:
>    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...", reated_at:
>    "2021-11-15 11:04:50.292970000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-11-15
>    11:04:50.292970000 +0000">}, missing required keys: [:id]
>
>    Did you mean?  post_category_url
>    admin_post_category_url

The @post_category exsist and corrrect, but simple_form doesn't work on test
Why @post_category got in :locale and how it repair?

Comment: This can't be answered without the code under test (like pretty much every question ever). We need the view and your routes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed all `link_to <subject>` to `link_to <subject>_path(id: subject.id)`
Why it needed for rspec I don't know